# Axios communicate with backend (LARAVEL) Api

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

So I have 2 separate projects, Vue3 (frontend) and Laravel (backend). I have this configuration in the VueJS:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://backend.com/api/'
axios.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
```

I can already login users via this Laravel passport from getting tokens when calling controller in Laravel:

```
if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){ 
    $user = Auth::user();
    $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken;
    $success['name'] =  $user->name;
    $success['_id'] =  $user->_id;
}
```

But I have SAML2.0 setup in my Laravel so the Event is happening in the backend not from frontend. I can generate token when user logged via SAML but I can't get it when calling the api from the frontend.

Can someone enlighten me? Here's my screenshot of backend response:

[image]

But returns null when calling the api from frontend:

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell using only screenshots for the app I/O

Answer (score 0):

@ Try with the below code to get a token. Hope it will work, if not work then let me know

```
// Login info Checking
if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){ 
    // Get Data from User Table
    $user=User::where('email','=',$data['email'])->first();
    // Set Response Data
    $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken;
    $success['name'] =  $user->name;
    $success['_id'] =  $user->_id;
}
```